# Run php server from batch command

Tags: php, batch-processing

Hello everyone I would like to launch a local php server ( php -S localhost:8888 public -t ) from a batch file but it doesn't work ....  Do you have an idea how to do that ? Also there are other commands before and after but while debugging I noticed that the problem came from there

Comment: Can you launch the server from command line? What OS are you running, what OS are you executing the batch file against, or on? This question needs significantly more detail.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your `PHP` in your environment path to access it from your `cmd`

this is how you add a `path` to your environment path in windows

[image]

Comment: I've already done this ...and besides when I type the command in the terminal it works normally, but when it's put in the batch file it doesn't work.